# Upcasting accesses

Tags: oop, subclass, ada

Let's say I have a `Planet`:

```
type Planet is tagged null record;
type Planet_Ref is access Planet'class;
```

Now I subclass it:

```
type Habitable_Planet is new Planet with null record;
type Habitable_Planet_Ref is access Habitable_Planet'class;
```

Now I define some variables:

```
p: Planet_Ref := Make_Planet;
hp: Habitable_Planet_Ref := Make_Habitable_Planet;
```

I would naively expect that assigning `p := hp` would work, because a Habitable_Planet is a subclass of Planet. But of course that won't work because every type defined with `type` is distinct and doesn't interoperate with any other type.

So I'd expect to have to declare Habitable_Planet_Ref to be a subtype of Planet_Ref to make this work. But the syntax doesn't seem to allow for this.

How do I make this work?

(Yes, I know I can use an explicit view conversion to cast a Habitable_Planet_Ref to a Planet_Ref, but that's really ugly and I'd like to avoid it.)

Comment: You can't avoid it.  Ada's type system is stricter than in other languages.  You can't say `x : float := 1;` even though you can do the equivalent thing in other languages, so it shouldn't be too surprising that there are other things Ada doesn't let you do that you can do in C++ or Java.  By the way, `p := Planet_Ref(hp);` is **not** a view conversion.  It is a value conversion, since you're converting an access value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ada recognizes types by name, so indeed you would need a view conversion here.
But if you are using Ada 2005, you can use anonymous access types instead. For instance:

```
hp: access Habitable_Planet'Class := Make_Habitable_Planet;
p: access Planet'Class := hp;   --  valid with anonymous access types
```

One the drawbacks of using anonymous access types is that the code is more
verbose (although in general you would not use them for local variables, but
as parameters to subprograms or as fields in a (tagged) record.
They also can't be used with Unchecked_Deallocation. In fact, I personally often
use them exactly because of that: when I have a field in a record which is of an
anonymous access type, I know that the record does not "own" the accessed data,
and therefore it should not free it (in fact, I would have to write some convoluted
code to free them).
And of course as per your request the result for type matching are slightly more
relax, which is nice too.

Comment: Yes --- that works beautifully. (I find the difference in behaviour between anonymous accesses and named accesses really unintuitive.) I have an example of it working here: http://ideone.com/ADO5It

Comment: I also managed to figure out a bunch of stuff which I was doing wrong which I shall write up in a separate answer, for clarity.

Comment: Sorry, that example was bad and wasn't demonstrating the right thing. _This_ is a fully working example. http://ideone.com/M79l0a

Answer (score 0):

ajb is correct in his comment. Ada is too strict for many practices you might be used to in other languages. An alternative would be to just not use objects and instead just simple records or discriminate records. I understand this may not be what you are looking for, but from my experience more can be done with less lines of code and the solution tends to me easier to understand.

Simple record

```
--...
type Rec_Planet is record
  --.. stuff
end record;
--...
type Rec_Habitable_Planet is record
  Planet : Rec_Planet := (others => <>);
  --.. stuff
end record;
```

Discriminate record

```
type Enum_Planet is (Normal_Planet, Habitable_Planet);
type Rec_Planet(Kind : Enum_Planet := Normal_Planet) is record
  -- rec_Planet stuff..
  case Kind is 
    when Habitable_Planet => -- Rec_Habitable_Planet stuff
    when others => null;
  end case;
end record;
```

Answer (score 0):

So @manuBriot gave me the answer I needed, but there were some other things I was doing wrong in my question which I should clarify because they'll confuse anyone else reading this question.

I was confusing the issue by using accesses. From Ada's point of view all accesses defined with `type` are distinct, so it never gets as far as looking at what the access is pointing at; it just disallows the assignment.

However, Ada does support implicit upcasting of class-wide types (and also discrete types, where an instance of a subtype will get implicitly cast to its parent type --- implement ALL the class hierarchies! But that's not really relevant here.) Example here:

```
With Ada.Text_IO; Use Ada.Text_IO;  
With Ada.Integer_Text_IO; Use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Prog is
    package Superclass is
        type Class is tagged record
            null;
        end record;

        procedure Announce(self: in out Class);

        subtype Var is Class'class;
    end;

    package body Superclass is
        procedure Announce(self: in out Class)
        is
        begin
            Put_Line("I am the superclass");
        end;
    end;

    package Subclass is
        type Class is new Superclass.Class with null record;
        procedure Announce(self: in out Class);
    end;

    package body Subclass is
        procedure Announce(self: in out Class)
        is
        begin
            Put_Line("I am the subclass");
        end;
    end;

    osuper: Superclass.Class;
    osub: Subclass.Class;

    vsuper: Superclass.Var := osuper;
    vsub: Superclass.Var := osub; -- implicit upclass here
begin
    vsuper.Announce;
    vsub.Announce;
end;
```

(It's in ideone here: http://ideone.com/M79l0a Interesting sidenote. If you define `subtype Var is Superclass.Var` in the Prog package, and then use Var in the definitions of vsuper and vsub, ideone's Ada compiler crashes.)

Of course, like all indefinite types, once the variable has been initialised then its type cannot be changed. So I can assign any Subclass.Object to vsub, but I can't assign a Superclass.Object to it. And of course I'm physically copying the object rather than referring to an object elsewhere.

Implicitly upcasting accesses to class-wide types should be safe. Because assigning to a class-wide type does a runtime instance check to make sure that the physical type of the objects are compatible, it ought not to be possible to accidentally corrupt objects like you can in C++ --- see [Overwriting an instance of a subclass with an instance of a superclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25379222/overwriting-an-instance-of-a-subclass-with-an-instance-of-a-superclass), for example. Therefore assigning to a dereferenced access shouldn't be a problem. However, it's 2100 at night and my brain has turned to sludge, so it's entirely possible that I'm missing something here. (Although given that when using anonymous accesses there aren't any problems, I suspect not.) Elucidation welcome...