# Overwriting an instance of a subclass with an instance of a superclass

Tags: c++, types, casting

Trying to figure something out (in Ada, actually) I came up with the following code. Why is it legal?

```
class Superclass {
public:
    virtual void Announce() {
        printf("I am the superclass\n");
    }
};

class Subclass : public Superclass {
public:
    void Announce() {
        printf("I am the subclass\n");
    }
};

int main() {
    Superclass osuper;
    Subclass osub;

    Superclass* p = &osub;
    *p = osuper;
    osub.Announce();

    return 0;
}
```

In `main()`, I create an instance of `Subclass`, then physically overwrite it with an instance of `Superclass`. I then successfully call a method of `Subclass` on the overwritten (and so corrupted) object.

I can't directly assign `osub = osuper`, because that makes no sense, but by going via a pointer I seem to bypass that. The above code compiles fine with no warnings, but by the time I call `osub.Announce()` the memory inside `osub` no longer contains a valid `Subclass` object.

This can't possibly be type safe (or even, like, ordinarily safe), but the compiler seems perfectly happy. Why?

Answer (score 6):

Using the = operator on an object is not invalid, and it doesn't overwrite anything, a default copy constructor will be used.
If you want to really overwrite the object in memory, try memcpy(p, &osub, sizeof(Superclass)). Now THAT would be an overwrite :)

See http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/

Comment: @MattMcNabb right, not in that specific case, but generally speaking about the assignment operator, it is

Comment: I guess you are referring to how it is recommended to implement the copy-assignment operator using the copy-and-swap idiom; if so this is something that you have to explicitly write, the implicitly-generated copy-assignment operator never does that; it does memberwise assignment

Comment: I was about to say that the default copy constructor is equivalent to the `memcpy()` --- but that's apparently not true; the default copy constructor doesn't copy the vtable pointer! So if you call `Announce()` on `p` then it'll call `Subclass::Announce()`, even though `p` will contain the members of the instance of `Superclass`. That's even more broken! Why is the compiler letting me do this?

Comment: @DavidGiven I don't understand your problem. Why do you think the compiler should deny using memcpy? The purpose of the compiler is NOT trying to understand your code and do some kind of quality check. If you need that, use an SCA tool.

Comment: @glezmen Sorry, I don't understand what you're saying here. I'm not using memcpy(); that's the point, really. I'm doing a sequence of completely valid operations and ending up with garbage. But I now realise why; see below.

Answer (score 2):

You are invoking the *copy-assignment operator*, not "physically overwriting". This is a function which, like any other function besides a constructor, may modify members of the object which already exist, it's not "magic".

Your object has no member variables so the implicitly-generated `operator=` call is a no-op.  There is no "corrupt object". `osub.Announce();` calls `Subclass::Announce` because `osub` is a `Subclass`.

The actual function called is `Superclass::operator=(Superclass const &);`.

The function `Subclass::operator=(Subclass const &);` loses in overload resolution because `osuper` does not implicitly convert to `Subclass const &`.

What you might be getting at is that if Subclass had member variables then the line `*p = osuper;` may leave the `osub` object in a state that was not intended by the designer of `Subclass`.

Comment: Re last paragraph: yes, exactly. I'm afraid that the rest of what you've said isn't actually relevant to what I wanted to know.

Comment: I don't know of any "solution" to this other than "don't do it"; it's a similar problem to how you can slice any object (e.g. `Derived d; Base b; b = d;`

Comment: Actually, you can't do that, as the compiler doesn't generate an implicit copy constructor for Derived which takes a Base. (Obviously if you add a custom copy constructor you can do anything.) Plus I'm not looking for a solution; I'm trying to understand why this allowed.

Comment: Can you suggest a language rule that would disallow it? Even if you make something specific to assignment operators, someone could still give `Base` a function `void f() { /* do something to Base that a Derived is not expecting */ }`. and then anybody can call `Base::f()` on your `Derived`.

Comment: To be clear, the derived object is not "corrupted" in the sense of undefined behaviour; however if the Derived object's logical state involved some Base variables being set in a particular way then the Derived object might break later. I think the only way to avoid this is to make `Base` only have pure virtual functions, or to otherwise design `Derived` in such a way that it can always cope with changes to `Base` members.

Comment: It might help if you gave a concrete example where the behaviour was broken

Answer (score 1):

The need is weird. 
When the constructor of subclass instance is called, the superclass's constructor function will be called to init member variables.
However, if you want this anyway, you can realize a member function like this:

```
Subclass& copy(const Superclass& superobject);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put a method in the subclass which returns the super class.
    SuperClass getSuperClass (){
        SuperClass sup;
        //copy contents on sup;
    return sup;
    }

Answer (score 0):

The executive summary of why this works seems to be: the implicit copy constructor hates you, and wants to hurt you.

The implicit copy constructor *looks* like it does a byte-for-byte copy of the object, thus making the assigned-to object identical to the assigned-from object. However, it doesn't do this. It merely copies the members. It especially doesn't copy the vtable pointer for the object. Assignment will probably suffer from the same problem (although I haven't checked this). I don't know anything about C++11 move.

If this violates any of your class hierarchy's contracts, or in any other way doesn't make any sense for your class hierarchy, then it basically sucks to be you.

The moral of this story is: classes should always inherit from `boost::noncopyable`.

(I'm aware that the copy constructor was grandfathered in from C. That's not an excuse.)